# Are there existence results for the heat equation on unbounded Lipschitz domain?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I am looking for a reference/ ideas on the following problem. Let $\Omega\subset\Bbb R^2$ be a Lipschitz domain (if it helps, the domain can be piecewise smooth with only one "kink", for example the domain $\Omega=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:-\infty<x<y,y>\mu\}$ for some $\mu>0$), and consider for some $0<T<\infty$,
$$\partial_tu-\Delta u=f\quad\text{in}\quad\Omega\times(0,T)$$
$$u|_{\partial\Omega\times(0,T)}=g$$
$$u|_{t=0}=h$$
where $f,g,h$ are sufficiently smooth etc.

I am also interested in the same problem with the second boundary condition $\beta(x,t)\cdot\nabla u+\alpha(x,t)u=g$ on $\partial\Omega\times(0,T)$, as well as the mixed problem, which has a Dirichlet boundary condition on $\{y=\mu\}$, and second boundary condition on the line $\{x=y\}$, the latter is for the case of the specific $\Omega$ given above.

I have seen existence uniqueness and regularity results for the non mixed problem (but for either type of boundary condition) for bounded Lipschitz domains, and unbounded sufficiently smooth domains, so really I am looking at a unison here i.e., unbounded and not sufficiently smooth.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the rectangular case at all? What have you done so far to address this problem?

Comment: I've focused mainly on the specific domain I mentioned, I have tried altering the proof in ladyzhenskayas book, which assumes $C^2$ boundary, in the proof they construct an operator that is written (non trivially) as a sum of local coordinate constant coefficient operators. I wanted to try to construct a sequence of operators defined for a smoothed version of the domain, and hoped to take a limit to produce an operator, but so far no luck.

Comment: The aim being the at the operator $R$ that is given defines the inverse to the operator that defines the pde (and BC's), this operator ($R$) is bounded and thus we get existence and uniqueness

Comment: You could try conformally mapping this region to a rectangular one to see what you get. Might be interesting.

Comment: An infinite rectangle or finite?

Comment: Leave it infinite. Think about $z^{\alpha}$ in the plane.

Comment: Do you mean like a half space, or an infinite strip bounded above and below?

Comment: Uniqueness is always a problem for the heat equation. But if you use $C_0$ semigroup conditions, then everything is much nicer.

Comment: Think about what you get if you map the quarter plane under $z^{\alpha}$. That is $(re^{i\theta})^{\alpha}=r^{\alpha}e^{i\alpha\theta}$ for $r \ge 0$ and $0\le\theta\le\pi/2$. Keep it simple, but I think you want to a corner at least, rather than trying to flatten everything out.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean like using polar coordinates, but mpping to the complex plane instead?

Comment: I was just pointing out how $z^{\alpha}$ maps; that's easier to see in polar, but that's not what you have to use.

Comment: I see, sorry I thought you meant I should only map the quarter plane part of my domain, I didn't realise it was to see how the map works, I will try this and see what happens :)

Comment: Conformal maps are good because of the Laplacian. And $z^{3/2}$ maps the first quadrant to a region related to yours. Then you should be able to use separation of variables.

Comment: Thanks! I will update when I have more progress :)